# How to run inline python in bash with variables?

Tags: python, bash, shell

I want to get run a python inline command together with variables from my bash script. It works without the import line.

```
for filename in *.txt; do
    OUT=$(python3 -c "import pprint\nprint('$filename')")
    mv $file $OUT
done
```

But I get the error message `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`.

Comment: Python supports semicolons as statement separators, what if you try to replace the `\n` with `; `?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\n` gets passed in verbatim, and doesn't make    sense to Python. The most expedient fix is probably to use a semicolon instead, which Python supports pretty much solely to allow you to write simple one-liners inside a script in another language.

```sh
    OUT=$(python3 -c "import pprint; print('$filename')")
```

You could also pass in an actual newline;

```sh
    OUT=$(python3 -c "import pprint
print('$filename')")
```

Though why do you `import pprint` when you are not using it? I guess you wanted to `pprint()` the filename, not `print()` it?

This could still fail if the filename contains a literal single quote. From the Python side, you could fix this by reading the string as a command-line argument.

```sh
    OUT=$(python3 -c "import pprint, sys; pprint.pprint(sys.argv[1])" "$filename")
```

As an aside, you [should not use upper case for your private shell variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization), and [quote the variable.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

```sh
for filename in ./*.txt; do
    out=$(python3 -c "import pprint, sys; pprint.pprint(sys.argv[1])" "$filename")
    mv "$file" "$out"
done
```

The added `./` avoids the problem that a filename which starts with a dash would be parsed as a (probably invalid) option to `mv`. Actually a better refactoring would be to perform the rename - and perhaps the loop, too! - in Python instead. Passing filenames correctly with quoting etc intact between tools is more challenging in shell script than it should be.

```sh
python3 -c 'import pprint, sys, shutil; for file in sys.argv[1:]: shutil.move(file, pprint.pformat(file))' ./*.txt
```